# Rails - Index action showing database record under post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here, but my index action is returning a bunch of information directly from the database underneath each record:

```
First Post!!!

Hello. This is my first blog post
[#<Post id: 1, user_id: nil, title: "First Post!!!", 
content: "Hello. This is my first blog post", created_at: "2016-02-26 20:51:57", 
updated_at: "2016-02-26 20:51:57">]
```

> index.html

```
= for p in @posts
  %h1
    = p.title
  %p
    = p.content
```

Comment: change `= for p in @posts` to `- for p in @posts`

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was doing something stupid like that...

Comment: btw, it's recommended to use iterators instead of `for` in ruby. ` @posts.each do |p|` is preferable

Comment: Please select my answer as accepted, that way other people in the community will help you when you ask more questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you are evaluating and outputting your `for`, in haml when you use `=` it is the same to use `<%= %>` in erb, it means that your code will be outputted once it is evaluated, that's why you are seeing that information from the database.

For solve your issue just use the "evaluator" tag in haml that is `-` it is the equivalent of `<% %>` in erb, that means your code will be ONLY evaluated and will not print any information to the screen.

Also as a suggestion do not use `for` when looping your objects in rails, use iterators like: `@posts.each do |p|` instead of `for` loop.